# Angular9/Ionic 5 Ion-Split-pane issues

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile

For Some reason beyond my comprehension I am having issues with the ion-split-pane element.

If I remove the split-pane element the router-outlet works just fine. and My nav is shown after login is successful. Only problem is I have a mobile feel web app :/ with a click to open menu on desktop screens as well. I know I could go CSS and bootstrap to come up with something. But it irks me that I cant figure this out. HELP!

It is:
A. Not doing the split pane thing based on the screen size
B. Somehow it interferes with pages being loaded into the router-outlet

app.component.html:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content" [when]="true">
    <ion-menu content="content" *ngIf="this.authInfo | async" contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
          <ion-menu-button slot="end">
            <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-menu-button>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="profile-section">
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let k of orderedKeys();">
            <ion-item (click)="handleClick(k)"  detail="false"  lines="none" class="active" [class.selected]="testSelection(appPages[k].name)">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="appPages[k].icon + '-outline'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{appPages[k].title}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    
    <ion-header *ngIf="this.authInfo | async">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{section}}</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" #content main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from './guards/auth-guard.service';
import { LandingPage } from './landing/landing.page';
import { AdminOnlyGuardService } from './guards/admin-only-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LandingPage
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-up',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sign-up/sign-up.module').then( m => m.SignUpPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-password',
    loadChildren: () => import('./forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then( m => m.ForgotPasswordPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'page-not-found',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page-not-found/page-not-found.module').then( m => m.PageNotFoundPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'contracts',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./contracts/contracts.module').then( m => m.ContractsPageModule)
  }
  // {
  //   path: 'landing',
  //   loadChildren: () => import('./landing/landing.module').then( m => m.LandingPageModule)
  // }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Angular 9/Ionic 5

I don't see why you would need to see other files, but then again I cant figure out what's wrong. So drop a line and I can share related files.

Comment: Share your `app-routing.module.ts` code

Comment: added app-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

To answer your 2 questions:

A: I think this is because you used `[when]="true"` in `<ion-split-pane>`.
Try to change the value according the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane#setting-breakpoints).

B: This is because router outlet should be outside the `<ion-split-pane>` element, so instead of:

`<ion-router-outlet id="main-content" #content main> </ion-router-outlet> </ion-split-pane>`

try with:

```
</ion-split-pane>
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content" #content main></ion-router-outlet>
```

Comment: amazing, helped me today!